# Codeigniter 2 routing with (:any) duplicates

Tags: php, routes, duplicates, codeigniter-2

Just got a question about codeigniters routing when you only want the first segment to be valid. Cant seem to find a good answer when googling.

So I have a basic route for my general pages:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'common/pages/view/$1';
```

Pages is the class and view is the method along with the name of the page as a variable (pretty much like the example on the ci manual).

This works fine when I go to:

```
www.mysite.com/mypage/
```

However when I then go to:

```
www.mysite.com/mypage/randomstring/
```

This also loads mypage which is essentially a duplicate.

Is their a way to tell the any route to only apply to the first segment and if more exist do a 404?

If worse comes to worse I will just add a check in the method to see if the 2nd segment exists, if so show_404 but just curious as to if it can be done purely in the routes.

Thanks for reading and I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use Regex instead?

```
$route['([^/]+)'] = 'common/pages/view/$1';
```

This would prevent the URL after your domain from containing / and if it does, it will call the default 404 page.

I haven't tested this but it "should" work ;)

Comment: perfect. Im not to great with regex but another reason to try and improve my skills on it. Thanks a lot. it did work lol :)

Comment: This does exactly the same thing as my hacky aproach tsk stk

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = "none_existent_controller";
$route['(:any)'] = "common/pages/view/$1";
```

Comment: Thats an awesome idea. Directing to a no existing controller is a little hacky though lol. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: well you could go to a controller specially setup to handle such a situation and call the show_404(); function

Comment: Since I got into codeigniter about a year ago I haven't looked back! It's fantastic, can't compare it to other frameworks as I haven't used any ;-) but I am blown away by codeigniter